# How to create an area cartogram in Shapefile format

Tags: shapefile, population

I am working with state level data on health insurance to create a map with each state color-coded based on that data. This is fairly straight forward but some of the largest states geographically are often the least populated. So I want to display my data as an area cartogram map based on population.

Essentially I want to use a map with the states shaped like below as my base shapefile layer. [image: Population Cartogram]

I found some resources on how to make an area cartogram map but none of them seem to output into a shapefile.

Comment: If you want states color-coded based on population *density*, calculate population density by dividing the state population by the area of the state. If you had a different type of cartogram in mind, please [edit] your question to include an example.

Comment: pretty sure there are some. best place to start looking would be the governmental or statistical authorities of your country. as an  alternative, if those spurces provide means to produce those geometries, you can likely work with whatever output format you get in any GIS you have access to, and export as shapefile *if* you need.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Hi everyone; I'm primarily using R and a little bit of qGIS. I think what ThingumaBob is suggesting is what I need to do. Essentially, I want to use a shp file layer that is based off something like https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55bb8935e4b046642e9d3fa7/t/5818e21df7e0ab31b4a3f522/1478025765751/ Sorry if that wasn't clear!

Comment: Try the cartogram3 plugin in QGIS. There's a tutorial for the previous version of this plugin here: http://learngis.uk/creating-cartograms-with-qgis-2-18/